# Ruby on Rails : undefined method `instructors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

I know there are lots of similar problems but none of those solutions work. I have a relational database. Specifically I have two tables that relate to each other: programs and instructors.

The relation between the tables is the following:

a program "has_many :instructors"
and an instructor "belongs_to :program"

here is the code of the tables' models:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :slug

  has_many :instructors
  has_many :degrees
  has_many :disciplines
  has_many :projects
  has_many :articles

  def to_param
    slug
  end
end

class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program

  has_attached_file :portrait,
    :storage => :s3,
    :path => "/pictures/:id/:filename"

  # has_attached_file :featured_picture
  validates_attachment_content_type :portrait, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

I also have a pretty simple view:

```
= render('layouts/menu')
 .infra-centered
  = render('navigation')
  .infra-row
.infra-col-12
  %h2 Animation
  -if @an.instructors.empty?
    %p.notes Add faculty
  - else
    %table
      %tr
        %th Name
        %th Position
        %th Office
        %th Phone
        %th Email
      - @an.instructors.order(:lastname).each do |instructor|
        %tr
          %td= instructor.firstname + " " + instructor.lastname
          %td= instructor.rank
          %td= instructor.office
          %td= instructor.phone
          %td= instructor.email
```

And the controller is:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def contacts
    @employees = Employee.all
    @an = Program.where(abbreviation: "an").first
    @gd = Program.where(abbreviation: "gd").first
    @il = Program.where(abbreviation: 'il').first
    @ph = Program.where(abbreviation: 'ph').first
  end
end
```

The problem is that RoR is not recognizing the relationship between the tables causing the line "@an.instructors.empty?" to fail with the following error: undefined method `instructors' for nil:NilClass

I don't know why is not working please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not necessarily caused by the relationship, but the fact that the `@an` variable is nil, indicating that there was no record with that abbreviation found. Perhaps, try implementing a check in your view for whether `@an` (or others), are nil before trying to use them.